# Salesforce OAuth error "unsupported_grant_type"

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to set up a Salesforce connected app following the instructions provided by Salesforce here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm

When executing the curl command as described in the above document, I am getting an "unsupported_grant_type" error.

```
curl https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=password' -d 'client_id=consumer-key' -d 'client_secret=consumer-secret' -d 'username=my-login@domain.com' -d 'password=my-password'
```

The domain, consumer-key, consumer-secret, username, and password have all been replaced by the actual values.

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any errors in SF setup, user's login history?

Comment: I can only see the browser logins which sort of makes sense. I am only trying to generate the OAuth token. I guess the next step when I actually use the token would be considered a login. I tried to change any of the parameters but they all result in the same error: grant type not supported.

Comment: Rather than using the curl command above as per Salesforce documentation, I tried the curl command described here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BCs9IAG. This gives me a different error message: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}. Also, this time it shows up in the login history as failed API security token required. Still not sure where the problems lies.

Comment: The curl in the previous comment does work. I did get the authentication failure to due IP restrictions.